# How dynamicly check checkboxes with compare object and value?

Tags: angular, filter

I have a list of groups like this:

```
{"data":
  [
    {"id":"221","title":"group1"},
    {"id":"18","title":"Group2"},
    {"id":"306","title":"Group3"},
    {"id":"19","title":"Group4"}
  ]
}
```

In the template I loop though all the groups of the above object and display them like this:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="user.group" multiple="true" name="group">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group.id" [selected]="ifIsInGroup(group.id)">
    {{ group.title }}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

In my page class I have an object with the groups the user already assigned to: 
`{ "mygroups":[{"title":"Group2","id":"18"}]}` the function for select or not select an option:

```
ifIsInGroup(itemID){
  if(what to do here?){
    return true
  } else { 
    return false;
  }
}
```

How to check if a mygroups item exist in the data (all groups) list? And return true sow the option is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to check if an itemId exists for any of the items in the all groups list?

You can update your `ifIsInGroup` function to use the `some` function, which returns a boolean:

```
this.allGroups.some(x => x.id == itemID;
```

So instead of doing an if/else statement to return true or false if an item exists in the list, update you function to:

```
ifIsInGroup(itemID){
  return this.allGroups.some(x => x.id == itemID;  //returns true if it exists, false if it doesn't exist in the list
}
```